# multiply values in xml file via c# form app

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make an XML editor for a game in C#.
I've got a C# forms app ready, but I need to figure out how to multiply values in the selected xml file.

The XML looks like this:

```
<missions>
<mission type="harvest" reward="2862" status="0" success="false">
    <field id="27" sprayFactor="0.000000" spraySet="false" plowFactor="0.000000" state="2" vehicleGroup="3" vehicleUseCost="520.447510" growthState="7" limeFactor="1.000000" weedFactor="1.000000" fruitTypeName="SOYBEAN"/>
    <harvest sellPoint="12" expectedLiters="10539.061523" depositedLiters="0.000000"/>
</mission>
<mission type="harvest" reward="2699" status="0" success="false">
    <field id="4" sprayFactor="0.500000" spraySet="false" plowFactor="0.000000" state="2" vehicleGroup="11" vehicleUseCost="490.897491" growthState="6" limeFactor="1.000000" weedFactor="1.000000" fruitTypeName="COTTON"/>
    <harvest sellPoint="17" expectedLiters="13012.056641" depositedLiters="0.000000"/>
</mission>
<mission type="harvest" reward="8620" status="0" success="false">
    <field id="6" sprayFactor="1.000000" spraySet="false" plowFactor="1.000000" state="2" vehicleGroup="8" vehicleUseCost="1567.417480" growthState="5" limeFactor="1.000000" weedFactor="1.000000" fruitTypeName="SUNFLOWER"/>
    <harvest sellPoint="12" expectedLiters="54337.136719" depositedLiters="0.000000"/>
</mission>
<mission type="transport" reward="307" status="0" success="false" timeLeft="114865506" config="WATER" pickupTrigger="TRANSPORT04" dropoffTrigger="TRANSPORT01" objectFilename="data/objects/pallets/missions/transportPalletBottles.i3d" numObjects="1"/>
```

I want to multiply all the values reward="xxxxx"

My c# code looks like this:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();
        string multiply = textBox1.Text;
    }

    XmlDocument missions;
    string path;
    private string lang;

    public void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            lang = "en";
        }
    }

    public void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            lang = "nl";
        }
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string strfilelocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            textBox2.Text = strfilelocation;
            path = strfilelocation;
            missions = new XmlDocument();
            missions.Load(path);
        }
    }

    public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lang == "en")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This tool is developed to make the wages of the contractjobs higher, thus giving you more money when you complete them. Select the desired percentage which you want the program to multiply the wages with, and select the missions.xml in your desired savegame. Click apply, and then save. You need to run this program every once in a while, to update the wages, or use it once and copy the file. (disclaimer: when you have raised wages, and you run the program again, and jobs with raised wages are still in missions.xml, the wages will get even higher than they were.)");
        } else if (lang == "nl")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This tool is developed to make the wages of the contractjobs higher, thus giving you more money when you complete them. Select the desired percentage which you want the program to multiply the wages with, and select the missions.xml in your desired savegame. Click apply, and then save. You need to run this program every once in a while, to update the wages, or use it once and copy the file. (disclaimer: when you have raised wages, and you run the program again, and jobs with raised wages are still in missions.xml, the wages will get even higher than they were.)");
        }
        }
```

Is there an easy way to do this? If yes, can someone point me in the direction? I'm not asking for all the code, just a little startup, because I'm stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance!

---

New error

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'

code:

```
var text = path;

        var xml = XElement.Parse(text);
        var rewards = xml
                      .Descendants()
                      .Where(d => d.Attribute("reward") != null)
                      .Select(d => d.Attribute("reward"));
        // Do something with rewards. For instance, displaying them in the console
        rewards.ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Value));
```

Comment: I.e. 2862*2699*8620*307?

Comment: No, textbox 1 gives a number, wich represents a percentage, So it would be like this: 2862\100*{textbox1 value}+2862 = ... and than that for every reward entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stripped down XML a bit to omit text we don't need. The code extracts all rewards. You can do with them whatever you need:

```
var text = @"
    <missions>
        <mission type='harvest' reward='2862' status='0' success='false'>
        </mission>
        <mission type='harvest' reward='2699' status='0' success='false'>
        </mission>
        <mission type='harvest' reward='8620' status='0' success='false'>
        </mission>
        <mission type='transport' reward='307' status='0' success='false' />
    </missions>";

var xml = XElement.Parse(text);
var rewards = xml
              .Descendants()
              .Where(d => d.Attribute("reward") != null)
              .Select(d => d.Attribute("reward"));
// Do something with rewards. For instance, displaying them in the console
rewards.ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Value));
```

Comment: @JustinRijsdijk Good appetite! 

Comment: So how would I fill te var text you've created with dynamic data? the form loads the xml file by an OFD, so I want that info to fill the text var. || Thanks @JohnyL

Comment: @JustinRijsdijk OFD - Open File Dialog? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, open File Dialog! @JohnyL

Comment: @JustinRijsdijk Then use `XElement.Load()` and pass it file path.

Comment: Whoops, jinxed myself, got this error now; System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.' @JohnyL code has been added under teh question.

Comment: @JustinRijsdijk I'm using not XmlDocument, but [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement).